# Positive definite semi-ordering

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wanted to ask why is positive definite semi-ordering is well defined only for Hermitian matrices (or symmetric matrices if restricted to the reals)?

I saw an extension to the definition of positive definite matrices to the asymmetrical case. Namely, we say that a real (unnecessary symmetric) matrix $M$ is positive definite in the wide sense if and only if $z^TMz>0$ for all non-zero vectors $z$. This is equivalent to that the symmetrical part of $M$, which is $\frac{M+M^T}{2}$, is positive definite in the narrow sense.

Why is not possible to define a semi-ordering using this extended definition without considering self-adjoint matrices?

Thank yo uall in advance,
Ziv Goldfeld

Comment: Are you sure you mean a "semi-ordering"? I don't think the second condition in [the definition of a semiorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiorder#Definition) is fulfilled. Perhaps you mean a partial order?

Comment: I guess it's partial order. How do you compare [0,1;0,0] and [0,0;1,0]?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can say that $A\leq B$ is $B-A$ is positive semi-definite. But to see why people not pay much attention to this, consider what you get when $A,B$ are complex numbers: you would be defining $a+ib\leq c+id$ if $b=d$ and $a\leq c$. For instance, 
$$
1+2i\leq 3+2i.
$$
Not a lot of information can be gathered from this, as you are basically considering the order of the reals for the real part, and fixing the imaginary part.

Comment: I see, but how does the self-adjoint case solves this problem you presented for the non self-adjoint case?